# Same git repository, same history, different commit hashes?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a clone of CPython on my own gitlab server from a few years ago. Total I just tried to pull/merge the latest from the the official github repository into my gitlab's repo, but it failed due to no common history.

All of the commits are there, some authors, commit messages dates etc. However all commit hashes are different. Anyone have any idea how this occurred? Did the import operation from github->gitlab do something different from a clone? Possibly a older gitlab behavior?

Thanks

Edit:
The cat-file from GitHub for the initial commit is:

---

```
tree 52384aa82c1f7785424544fc3ee003729b07ac12  
author Guido van Rossum <guido@python.org> 650211915 +0000 
committer Guido van Rossum <guido@python.org> 650211915 +0000  

HG:extra convert_revision:svn%3A6015fed2-1504-0410-9fe19d1591cc4771/python/branches/legacy-trunk%402161  

Initial revision
```

---

While the cat-file from my Gitlab version for the initial commit is:

---

```
tree 52384aa82c1f7785424544fc3ee003729b07ac12  
author Guido van Rossum <guido@python.org> 650211915 +0000  
committer Guido van Rossum <guido@python.org> 650211915 +0000  

Initial revision
```

---

Wonder how the HG/SVG extra information got lost.

Comment: well I guess you can find out which is the first sha1 which is different and then examine the commit to see what is the difference, as there must, obviously be one. That said you can merge each other in order to recreate a common point in their history and ease merge (or even rewrite the whole history of one)

Comment: You will also see this same behavior (same changes, but new id) if a rebase has occurred. I don't know enough about import/export.migration

Comment: They are different all the way back actually. interesting..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hash of an object is completely determined by the object's content.

Find the root commit(s) of the two repositories and inspect their data (`git cat-file -p`).  *Something* will be different.  All other differences stem from there.  Otherwise, the histories match up to some point, at which point there is something different and then the histories diverge.

In general this kind of thing happens when someone does a massive `git filter-branch` to rewrite history.  Cloning definitely *does not* do this, but importing from some other version control system (SVN or Mercurial) might do this if the importer does not set all of each commit's data from the other VCS, or if you run items through different mappers (e.g., Mercurial committers don't match Git so one needs a map).

Edit per edit: it's clearly the `HG:extra` line that is different.  (The `tree`, `author`, `committer`, and main commit text lines are the same.)  `HG:extra` data is specific to Mercurial; in this case it appears to be due to importing to Mercurial from SVN.  Python was maintained in Mercurial for some time, but is now maintained in Git.  Perhaps Python was initially maintained in SVN.  This makes sense given the dates: as noted [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/node92.html), Python existed before either SVN or Mercurial; SVN was created in 2000, with 1.0 released in 2004; Mercurial was created in 2005.  ([Git also dates to 2005.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git))

Comment: Thanks, I've added the cat-file -p information from the initial commits, which were different hashes

Comment: Right, so the puzzle is still, how did I manage to get a full git repo with all history, but it didn't have that included in it.. Thanks a lot for your help.